# netty-tcnative not picking up configuration in jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms

Tags: java, netty, vert.x

My application is a Vert.x based application and recently switched to use `OpenSSLEngineOptions` which uses `netty-tcnative` for listening on a secure protocol. Earlier I was using code like below in order to disable older TLS versions, but post switching to `OpenSSLEngineOptions`, the same does not seem to be working.

```
Security.setProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms", "RC4,TLSv1");
```

Note that I am not allowed to modify the `java.security` file as the box may be used to run other unrelated Java applications.

Seems like I have an option to use `io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerOptions#addEnabledSecureTransportProtocol` method to achieve the same (actually reverse, but not yet tested), but this involves a code change and thus a release which means a process to follow. Please share if any inputs around this if tcnative supports any other system properties that can limit the protocols exposed.

Comment: This sounds like a netty "bug". Please open an issue and we will try to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. Have opened the bug: https://github.com/netty/netty-tcnative/issues/530